# Can +48v DC Voltage be achieved by reversing the terminal of -48v DC voltage supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have a -48v dc supply that was achieved by grounding +48 terminal of the rectifier. Now can I get a +48v dc supply by simply ungrounding the pos terminal and grounding the neg terminal  ?

Comment: If the supply originally worked as +48V, I don't understand the logics of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases a telecom -48V PSU does not connect to chassis neither the positive, neither the negative terminal. However it is good to check this first if the device you will power have ground (earth) connections through other cables.

If earthing is not a problem, there is no other reason not to use this power supply. Just connect its (-48V) terminal to your GND and its 0V terminal to your +48V.

Comment: You didn't understood the question:  The PSU is 48V and the +48V terminal was grounded and 0V terminal became -48V. Now the OP asks if this PSU can work as before by swapping the earth terminal ???!! Like: My car goes backward because I shifted to reverse gear. The question is, will my car go forward again if shift the gear in forward?

Comment: You're right. From the OP's question isn't clear (at least for me) if the connection between (+) and GND is made outside the PSU on its terminal block or inside the PSU. If it is inside it should be checked wheather it is connected in one place only and removing it would affect something else or not.

Answer (score 0):

**First trace why and where your supply is grounded, then see if th ground can be swapped to the -ve terminal from the +ve terminal.  This is almost always done by the user with jumper wires.**. A "floating supply" is the norm for safety reasons and " grounded " for EMI reasons. But safety is guaranteed with leakage filter design to 0.25 or 0.5mA max.

A power supply is generally floating with an earth ground contwct which you "define" as 0 volts.

Therefore you can easiliy **connect +Out to Earth Gnd** and get -48V with respect to "earth ground" on -Out.

> Remember that we call any logical "local ground" as 0 volts reference and it can be floating or Earth grounded. Then we define these ground symbols on the schematic. So "ground" is merely a logical 0V and also an analog zero volts, but often meant as "earth ground" by a lazy man's description.  We call floating grounds on logic diagrams also as "ground" (Like ground zero) then decide if we want them earth grounded as needed.

So 0V ='Ground' and Earth Ground implies connection to a building ground via power cord or some other means.

Comment: What if the power supplies negative terminal is internally referenced to ground? You can't just reference any power supply's positive terminal to 0V

Comment: I have no idea why anyone making a Telecom type supply voltage would ever ground it internally, wiping out some of it's customer base and also significantly making creepage stress greater due to the HF transformer coupling capacitance for HIPOT tests, but hypothetically, you are correct. Show me one example. Jumpers or screws for crimp lugs are "external"

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question also, but for whatever reason one of the terminals might possibly be referenced internally to ground. All I'm saying is you've got to check it or you'll short it out.

Comment: I thought that would be obv.

Comment: 5% of the users here would probably get polarity wrong if given a red and black wire, some things are not obv

Comment: and 95% get wrong that a GNd is just 0V ref and may be floating from earth ground but are afraid to admit it. ;)